# Is possible to store and access to object instances without using a data structure?

Tags: java

The question may be ridiculous but it's posed in the confines of an assignment. I'm not looking for code as that would be cheating the assignment; just an answer either pointing in the right direction or telling me it's not possible.

I need to create instances of a class and access them individually but I can't store them in a data structure. Is there a way to call getters looping through instances of classes without having them stored in a data structure? Again, not looking for code.

```
public class Things{
    private int value;
    private int otherValue;

    // constructor
    public Things()

    // getters and setters
```

Now if I create four or five instances in a row with

```
Things things = new Things()
things.setValue(data)
things.setOtherValue(data)
```

but don't save them in a data structure, is there a way to access the individual instances?

Comment: Use the variables you assigned them to.

Comment: You cannot access to something that it's not stored and referenced from your code. The only way I see you could do this if you don't know how many of them you need is by creating a kind of linked list using your `Things` class.

Comment: You're already accessing it by using things.set..().

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Can't use a data structure of any kind.

Comment: @Mad Physicist gave me the answer I figured I would get but not being familiar with Java I wasn't sure.

Comment: Then the answer is **NO**

Comment: Is serializing them to a file on disk an option?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example `things` refer to one instance of your class `Things` and it does not need to be stored in list (where did you get the impression that is mandatory to store object instances in list for them to be accessible is beyond me). As long as there is reference to it (and there is no reason there should not be after the object was just initialized, at least in short time space) it continues to exist and is not eligible for garbage collection. So following this, you could create `things2` that would be another instance. And then you can call and access the instance methods bys using `things1...n.method()`. If this is not the answer you wanted, please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not storing the instances in a data structure means that you have to have an individual variable to point to each one. For example, if you wanted to have three things:

```
 Things thing0 = new Things();
 Things thing1 = new Things();
 Things thing2 = new Things();
```

Then you could access each thing individually, for example to set the data:

```
thing0.setValue(data);
thing1.setValue(data);
thing2.setValue(data);
```

This is not efficient, as you pointed out. It would be better to make an array of things. If the array counts as a data structure, you are SOL, but if not:

```
Things[] things = new Things[3]; // The array is filled with `null` references to start with
for(int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    things[i] = new Thing();
    things[i].setValue(data);
}
```

The really sneaky way to do it would be to use java reflection. Reflection allows you to access the properties of a class or object programatically. If you have fields called `thing0` through `thingN` in your class, you can loop over them using reflection. I think this is probably outside the scope of your class, so will not post the code here unless you really need it.

Comment: This is what I thought. I can't use an array, linked list array list, etc... So it looks like I'll have to use individual names which is going to be difficult as these instances are being created as tokens are read in from a text file and the number of tokens will vary. They will always be relatively small (less than 10) but still a pain. I was hoping there was a way to use a variable in the instantiation but reading through the API it doesn't appear that's the case. No code needed.